# Typecheck error while passing an array of ReactNode to a functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typechecking

I have a component which is passing an Array of ReactNode to another component.

```
    const getOptions = (links: Array<Links>): Array<ReactNode> => {
        const options: Array<ReactNode> = [];
        links.map((link): void => {
            options.push(
                <Link
                    href={link.path}
                    key={link.page}
                >
                    {link.label}
                </Link>
            );
        });
        return options;
       };
<<<<<some code>>>>>>
<Dropdown dropDownOptions={getOptions(dropdownLinks)} />
```

My Dropdown component:

```
const Dropdown = ({ dropDownOptions }: any): JSX.Element => {}
```

so the problem I have here is when I use any as dropdown option type I get a warning:

> Object pattern argument should be typed with a non-any type

But when I use Array as a type I get the following error:

> Property 'dropDownOptions' does not exist on type 'any[]'

I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: I think that when you do `{ dropDownOptions }: any[]` you are saying that the object `{ dropDownOptions }` is an array of any[]``. This is wrong, it is an object not an array.

Comment: @Magofoco but the prop I am passing is an Array<ReactNode>. I am not sure what's a right type to use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're specifying a type on a destructured property, you need the same structure in the type signature as well, so instead of `{ dropDownOptions }: Array<ReactNode>`, it needs to be

```
const Dropdown = ({ dropDownOptions }: { dropDownOptions: Array<ReactNode> }) => (
  <div>...</div>
)
```

or just

```
const Dropdown = ({ dropDownOptions }: { dropDownOptions: ReactNode[] }) => (
  <div>...</div>
)
```

As an unrelated note, the code uses `map`, but it's not an actual map as it builds the result with side effects and discards the returned array. You could rewrite it as a purely functional map like this:

```
const getOptions = (links: Array<Links>) =>
  links.map(link => (
    <Link href={link.path} key={link.page}>
      {link.label}
    </Link>
  ))
```

The return-type signatures will all be inferred by the compiler.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFCiSxwDemVMAchACZZwC%20cIiXKU8MWrggA7VPAAywKQGs4AXjgAKMMTCoAXMzgALSgQOyoigOYBuOLiPAANl0pSD2MZx78AlGoA%20OAAeLmAANwDggHowyJoYAE8wXgVldHUWMGQYI3MYSylbOGyrLHzC4qdkACMsJwrrfhoaSRl4ABEdLggAdyk1TRZXCDAOvqkAeTAYYGl0PgNhnXH%206dn5gwBBKChkRODPfG8sIL5-VSCNGjgQuICAOieY%205pfFrbZODKYdbmZAAKAFdUEZBhonIolPo4Ds9gc0tCAr5trt9oc2CcgpdmDdbvZ5vBRhsZKj4RivNxToMANoAXRseNukPSDxAyDAGghUJRcHCEGAXECuPxorgxP%20qAeYBBRmuYoVIURTMVCpMWAIqiYLKU0pyRj4KtVoqUWESWp1erKhuN%20ICRttzEt1TqThtjpiiPtqt8jNF5z9%20MoMCBUAGEvmjL4jNahO%20WF%20M0l4J1MLh6MRqGRgTxqbZHO5ymF8vxwURxlMFqhetyAlN5u11dKWD43rFjeUDxd9Xdt09ULbvnesfacHq8HUwS6ox6-TgIzGEz%208y1P2XMg09N8Ami9qAA)